# Autofac Class only implementation

Tags: vb.net, autofac

I am trying to implement a class that on first call get some data from a database and subsequent calls to this class will return the same data for the lifetime of the application, even then new instances of this class are called.     Is this possible?

Here is my sample attempt, the issue is I get `Object not set to an instance of the Object`.

```
Public Class session
  Implements IContainerProviderAccessor

  Shared _containerProvider As IContainerProvider
  Private _IUserSessionService As IUserSessionService ' interface to stores data
  Public Property Usersession As IUserSessionService
      Get
          Return _IUserSessionService
      End Get
      Set(value As IUserSessionService)
          _IUserSessionService = value
      End Set
  End Property

  Public ReadOnly Property ContainerProvider As IContainerProvider Implements IContainerProviderAccessor.ContainerProvider
      Get
          Return _containerProvider
      End Get
  End Property


  Public Function GetConnection() As String
      Dim UserSessionDetail As New UserSessionDetails
      ' Do we have a container if not register one 
      If IsNothing(_containerProvider) Then
          RegisterConnection()
          Dim UserSessionDetail As New UserSessionDetails
          UserSessionDetail.connection_string = GoAndGetOneFromOtherSource
          Usersession.AddSession(UserSessionDetail)
          Return UserSessionDetail.connection_string
      Else
          Usersession.GetUserSession()
          Return UserSessionDetail.connection_string
      End If
  End Function


  Private Sub RegisterConnection()
      Dim builder As ContainerBuilder = New ContainerBuilder()

      builder.RegisterType(Of UserSessionService).As(Of IUserSessionService).InstancePerRequest()

      'Auto Fac Binding 
      _containerProvider = New ContainerProvider(builder.Build())

  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Yeah of course it's possible, define your data and method as static, check to see if you already have data, if so return it, if not then do the fetch...

Comment: In terms of Autofac, this can be done by taking a dependency on a singleton object, or making your object a singleton.  Whenever another object declares a dependency on `session` then it will use the same object.  To be honest though, this looks a bit of a mess to me.  `IContainerProviderAccessor` should only be used to extend the HttpApplication object, not anything like this.  Perhaps review the [integration docs](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webforms.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your `IUserSessionService` as a singleton in *Autofac* and inject it in your `SessionStore` class constructor (I use `SessionStore` instead of `Session` to have conflict with native `Session` class). 
This way, each time you get a `SessionStore` instance, it will use only one instance of your `IUserSessionService` implementation.

your `SessionStore` will look like this :

```
public class SessionStore : ISessionStore
{
    public SessionStore(IUserSessionService userSessionService)
    {
        this._userSessionService = userSessionService;
    }    

    private readonly IUserSessionService _userSessionService; 

    public String ConnectionString
    {
        get 
        {
            // do what you want with _userSessionService
        }
    }
}
```

and your registration will look like this.

```cs
builder.RegisterType<XUserSessionService>().As<IUserSessionService>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<SessionStore>().As<ISessionStore>().InstancePerRequest();
```

To get the `ISessionStore` instance you can use the property injection in the `Page` object

see [structuring pages and user controls for Dependency Injection](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/webforms.html#structuring-pages-and-user-controls-for-di) from the documentation for more information.

```cs
// MyPage.aspx.cs
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
  // This property will be set for you by the PropertyInjectionModule.
  public ISessionStore SessionStore { get; set; }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    // Now you can use the property that was set for you.
    label1.Text = this.SessionStore.ConnectionString;
  }
}
```

Or access the `IContainerProviderAccessor` if you try to access the session outside of a page.

```cs
ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope = ((IContainerProviderAccessor)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).ContainerProvider.RequestLifetime;
ISession session = lifetimeScope.Resolve<ISessionStore>();
```